# Why do @ManytoOne or a @OnetoMany create issues in SpringBoot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have some entities defined in my backend application which have a couple of @ManytoOne and @OneToMany relationships, but one each execution in psequel that each of the foreign and primary key relationships have created additional structures. And I see this exception on execution I am not sure how to revert

> Hibernate: create table user_locations (user_id int4 not null,
>   locations_id int4 not null) Hibernate: alter table if exists
>   location_user_id add constraint FKfsq9me9k3dj93oujbfgplkfrx foreign
>   key (user_id_id) references user 2019-04-08 15:18:29.001  WARN 2023
>   --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error
>   executing DDL "alter table if exists location_user_id add constraint
>   FKfsq9me9k3dj93oujbfgplkfrx foreign key (user_id_id) references user"
>   via JDBC Statement
>
> ```
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists location_user_id add constraint
> ```
>
> FKfsq9me9k3dj93oujbfgplkfrx foreign key (user_id_id) references user"
>   via JDBC Statement

This is how my User table looks like :

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private String gmailToken;
    private String emailAddress;

    @Id
    private int Id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Location> locations;

}
```

Location Entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class Location {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String countryCode;
    private Point geoCordinates;
    private double googleRating;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private ArrayList workingHours = new ArrayList<WorkingHours>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> userId;

}
```

Is there something that I am missing here.

Edited to add:

I have changed the User Entity to look like this :

```
public class User {
    private String gmailToken;
    private String emailAddress;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<Location> locations;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<ReviewRequest> reviewRequests;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<Response> responseForRequests;

    public User(String gmailToken){
        this.gmailToken =gmailToken;
    }
}
```

And the location Entity to look like this :

public class Location {

```
private String name;
private String country;
private String countryCode;
private Point geoCordinates;
private double googleRating;
private String phoneNumber;
private ArrayList workingHours = new ArrayList<WorkingHours>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int Id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "location")
private List<User> userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "location")
private List<Customer> customerId;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID")
private List<ReviewRequest> reviewId;
```

}

I am still facing issues creating single tables and creating foreign key columns in the given User table.

Looks like the mappedBy and the @JoinColumn seems to be incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You should specify the `@JoinTable` on the owning side of the relationship (unless you are fine the hibernate naming defaults)

**2)** Specify the owned side by adding `mappedBy` on one of the entities:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Location> locations;
```

Comment: This has been resolved. I needed a much clearer understanding of the relationships between 2 entities and these 2 links were very useful for me to ensure the right mapping between the entities.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many, https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column